# Is rapier considered a light melee weapon

Tags: dnd-3.5e

For duel wielding penalties, I was not sure if duel wielding rapiers would allow me to use the two weapon fighting feat or not.

Comment: What does the book say?

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the [weapons table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#martialWeapons) under Martial weapons, we can see a list of all Light melee weapons (which *does not* include Rapier), followed by a list of (non-light) One-Handed melee weapons (which *does* include Rapier).

Looking at the description of [Rapier](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#rapier), we can see that it can be used in *some* ways like a light weapon (Weapon Finesse; no extra Strength bonus for using two-handed), but is not *actually* a light weapon for any other purpose.

> You can use the Weapon Finesse feat to apply your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier to attack rolls with a rapier sized for you, even though **it isn’t a light weapon** for you. You can’t wield a rapier in two hands in order to apply 1½ times your Strength bonus to damage.

Since it doesn't specify that it counts as light for two weapon style, then it defaults to what it *actually* is, which is a one-handed (non light) weapon.

Comment: Over-sized Two-Weapon fighting will take care of that penalty.

Answer (score 2):

The *oversize two weapon fighting* feat would allow you to fight with two rapiers. The feat is on page 111 of the Complete Adventurer book. It has a pre-requisite of two weapon fighting and Strength score of 13.

Answer (score -1):

While using two rapiers would be really bad style and taste (piercing weapons in general are not suited for dual-wielding as the attack motion leaves you quite open when switching the attack hand) it should be possible to use it with another type of weapon alongside it, such as a (parrying) dagger, using a RL example. Rapiers are THE fencing weapon and saying it's not a light weapon to prevent people from using two of them is not the smartest way to handle it. Our HB says you can dualwield with one rapier, but not two of them. The way it's written on the list makes no sense, no matter how you twist it.

Comment: Fighting with two rapiers was done historically, though it wasn't as common as rapier & dagger.